# Mercurial error: Failed to import extension hgext.gpg

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

I trying to enable gpg extension that comes with Mercurial to sign my change sets.

I am using the following two lines to enable the extension in the hgrc file:
[extensions]

```
hgext.gpg= FILEPATH
```

After I have added these lines to the hgrc file, I am getting the following error:

```
***Failed to import extension hgext.gpg from ...location...: Non-ASCII character '\xf3' in file ...location... on line 1, 
but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: And does the file in fact contain a non-ascii character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I read [GPG Extension Wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GpgExtension)

> This extension is currently being distributed along with Mercurial

and **Configuration** section also

> Configure your .hgrc to enable the extension by adding following lines:

```
[extensions]
hgext.gpg=
```

(see difference with yours)